# condition with eval {php}

Tags: php

```
<?php
eval("if (1==1){");
echo ('abc');
eval("}");
?>
```

Then i get a error :
Parse error: parse error in C:\wamp\www\test\index.php(2) : eval()'d code on line 1
abc
Parse error: parse error in C:\wamp\www\test\index.php(4) : eval()'d code on line 1
How to fix?

Comment: I want to make a template egine

Comment: You want to use a template engine to make a template engine?

Comment: No. make a template engine. Answer my question please

Comment: Snoob, you might do well to look at the code for other template engines. They probably accomplish your goals without requiring code like this.

Comment: template engine using eval is most terrible thing a developer can imagine. I am pity you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should **really** try to avoid using `eval` if at all possible. It presents an enormous and nearly unsurmountable security risk. I have never in my career come across a good reason to use this function. If you post an example, maybe we can help you find a way to accomplish your goal without this immense risk.

Disclaimer aside, I think the issue is that you're starting an expression in the `eval` that needs to be complete.

You could try this instead:

```
<?php
    $test = eval("return 1==1;");

    if($test)
    {
         echo 'abc';
    }
```

---

**edit:**

The goal is to do something like this:

```
[if {expression}][blog_title][endif]
```

Here is an idea. Instead of allowing the user to enter any expression, just use a variable, which the user can set. For example:

```
[if should_show_blog_title][blog_title][endif]
```

Then, the user could do this (pseudo-ish code, since I'm not sure what your templating API looks like):

```
$template = new Template();

// shows blog title
$template->set_variable('should_show_blog_title', 1 == 1); // 1 == 1  is true, so the variable is true
$template->set_variable('blog_title', 'Awesomesauce Blog!');

// doesn't show title
$template->set_variable('should_show_blog_title', 1 == 0); // 1 == 0 is false, so the variable is false
$template->set_variable('blog_title', 'Awesomesauce Blog!');
```

Another idea would be to provide a limited number of operators or functions that the user could use. Instead of `eval`ing it, you have to parse it. For example:

```
[if not_empty(blog_title)][blog_title][end if]
```

Then when you parse and compile the template (insert the data in, basically), you look for these special functions and translate them in to PHP. This is basically whitelisting, since you're only letting the user perform a very restricted subset of functionality.

You should look at [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/), which kind of follows the first idea. The implementation is actually pretty simple. The PHP implementation of mustache is here: [mustache.php](http://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php). You could look through the samples and some code to see if you could get some ideas.

One thing to keep in mind, is that if you're `eval`ing, the templating engine isn't going to be as user-friendly, because then the user has to write valid PHP in their conditions. Part of the appeal of mustache is that it's so simple and incredibly easy to use. I'm an experienced PHP developer, and while I can hack in PHP all day long, I still prefer mustache for templating because it just lets me get to the point.

Comment: Not sure why I was downvoted.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this is my problem:
[if somecondition]
[blog_title]
[endif]
But i don't know how to write a template engine with condition like this :(

Comment: Wish I could upvote you more, notJim.

Comment: If the string comes from the user or another third party, you're right. But if you control both the code containing the `eval()` and the string it is executing, it poses no greater risk than regular code. Plus, if deal with JSON much, you've probably used it. Prior to native browser support, which is still very new, `eval()` has always been the fallback method to get the data into the browser.

Comment: you've been downvoted for corrupting a 15 year old child, pushing them to evil ways. Don't be silly, nobody cares of disclaimers. Sometimes I think that for a few reputation points you all ready to help a murderer.

Comment: Uh, they were already "corrupted" by thinking to use `eval` in the first place. I don't see how downvoting my answer, which devotes most of its text to suggesting ways to avoid `eval` helps anyone. You can't eliminate poor programming by pretending it doesn't exist.

Comment: STOP HERE, i will not use eval .................. (bad english :D)

Comment: @ Col. Shrapnel : I am not murderen, just a newbie coder :D

Comment: @davidtbernal I just wanted to say thank you for that answer ; I was about to do what I never wanted to do: use eval() but I felt like I had no choice. In fact I do, and your answer reminded me of that.

Answer (score 3):

Simple ...

```
<?php
eval(
  "if (1==1){".
  "echo ('abc');".
  "}");
?>
```

Things in `eval('`...`')` must be a self completed expression or statement and '`}`' is not.

Comment: I'm thinking this is a better answer. Explains WHY he is getting the error. I have a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437403/php-eval-logical-operator-error