# PHP eval() logical operator error

Tags: php, wordpress, eval, logical-operators

Why does

`if (isset($_SESSION['location']) AND !empty($_SESSION['location']))`

work while

`if (isset($_SESSION['location']) && !empty($_SESSION['location']))`

does not?

I'm using eval() to process PHP in a wordpress page. It makes no sense to me why PHP chokes on `&&` and not `AND`. The docs don't say anything specifically and no one else seems to have a clear answer.

Thanks for your input.

**EDIT**

Not that it really matters, but I use eval() in a WP template:

```
            $sContent   = get_the_content();
            $sContent   = apply_filters('the_content', $sContent);
            $sContent   = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $sContent);

            eval(' ?>'. $sContent .'<?php ');
```

Comment: And where or how do you use `eval`?

Comment: in a WP template page, see edit.

Comment: The code as given works assuming `$_SESSION['location']` contains a value: http://codepad.org/0FIzG13c

Comment: Have you tried changing the eval() to an echo() and seeing if the &&s get parsed into something?  I had an issue like that because of single quote/double quote misusage.

Comment: but it doesn't work when using `&&`. Both session variables exist. I can also break it into 2 conditional statements and it works, just not when i use `&&`.

Comment: And where exactly is `if (isset($_SESSION['location']) && !empty($_SESSION['location']))`? In `$sContent`?

Comment: gigawatt, I think that's it. Rings a bell on an issue I've had before. Actually makes a lot of sense. I'll check now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress converts the `&&` to `&#038;&`.

I've run into an issue like this before, so it's good to know. I do most of the logic in that PHP WP template, so this is no big deal, jsut as long as I understand what's going on.

Thanks go to GigaWatt for pointing this out and reminding me of long lost memories.