# How do I change php if statement based on a variable without repeating code?

Tags: php, if-statement

Let's say i have this:

```
if( $row['date'] == "$date" && $row['datestatus'] !== "NOT STARTED" ) {
    //big chunck of code
}
```

That means show any status except for not started. Now I want to show all statuses if a variable is 1.  Let's say I have a variable like this:

```
$var = 0;
```

That variable can be a 1 or 0 depending on user interaction. If it's a 0, work like that above if statement. If it's a 1, show records with all statuses. Basically like this:

```
if( $row['date'] == "$date" ) {
    //big chunck of code
}
```

What I don't want to do is something like this:

```
if ($var==0) {
    if( $row['date'] == "$date" && $row['datestatus'] !== "NOT STARTED" ) {
        //big chunck of code
    }
} else {
    if( $row['date'] == "$date" ) {
        //same big chunck of code
    }
}
```

I tried doing something like this, but it didn't work:

```
if ($var==0) {
    $phpextended = '&& $row["datestatus"] !== "NOT STARTED"';
} else {
    $phpextended = '';
}
if( $row['date'] == "$date" $phpextended ) {
    //big chunck of code
}
```

Possible duplicate Q&A didn't help. What helped was the answers on this page.

Comment: is the "big chunk of code" the same?

Comment: You're probably looking to use eval() to evaulate a string as php code.

Comment: big chunk is the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [condition with eval {php}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615475/condition-with-eval-php)

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating it - isn't it just `if( $row['date'] == $date && ($var == 1 || $row['datestatus'] !== "NOT STARTED" ))` ?

Comment: You could use a ternary operator, right? Something like `if ($row['date'] == $date && ($var == 0 ? $row["datestatus"] !== "NOT STARTED" : true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($var==0 && $row['date'] == "$date" && $row['datestatus'] !== "NOT STARTED" || 
   $var==1 && $row['date'] == "$date"){
      //big chunck of code
}
```

Comment: I had forgot to change a variable name from this example to my real variable name. After I did that, this answer worked.

Answer (score 2):

You need and `OR` statement:

```
if( $row['date'] === $date 
    && 
    ($row['datestatus'] !== "NOT STARTED" || $var === 1)
) {
    //big chunck of code
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. basically i need this part to disappear (or not be used) if var equals 1 - $row['datestatus'] !== "NOT STARTED"... if var equals 0 then use it.

Comment: @leoarce That is exactly what is happening here.

Comment: Whether var is 1 or 0, the record with datestatus of NOT STARTED is not showing up.

Comment: @leoarce Then either the date does not match or `$var` is not equal to `1`. Is `$var` an Integer? Note that I use `===` so it checks both for value **and** the type. You should `var_dump();` all 4 values to check what they are exactly.

Comment: I forgot to change one of my example variable names from the example here to my real variable name, but even after I did that, it still didn't work, but then the other answer on this page started working after I changed the variable name.